# Android HttpURLConnection always throws exception

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
public class HttpURLConnectionExample  {
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla 5.0";
    // HTTP GET request
    public ArrayList<dispencer> sendGet() throws Exception {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.9";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    //print result
    ArrayList<dispencer> dispList = new ArrayList<dispencer>();
    String[] strRows = response.toString().split("@");
    for (int i= 0; i <strRows.length; i++) {
        dispencer disp = new dispencer(strRows[i]);
        if (!disp.isOk) continue;
        dispList.add(disp);
        System.out.println(disp.indirizzo);
    }
    return dispList;
}
}
```

I call the method `sendGet` like this.

```
        HttpURLConnectionExample httpFnd= new HttpURLConnectionExample();
            ArrayList<dispencer> listAr = new ArrayList<dispencer>();
            try{
                listAr = httpFnd.sendGet();
            }
            catch (Exception Exception){

                fndLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                System.out.println("exception handled");
            }
```

Whenever I try to call **sendGet** I always get the message exception handled and never recieve my `arrayList` back, just like connection was never established.
When I call the method I also get this error

> D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default

, is it the cause of my problem ?

thanks for the help.

EDIT i saw i need to use asyncTask to preventivo throwing the exception Andy suggestion about how i have to implement it ?

Comment: add your complete error log

Comment: what exception is trhown?

Comment: this is the error log      02/14 18:03:54: Launching app
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.example.lele.condomadv/lib
Hot swapped changes, activity restarted
E/EGL_emulation: tid 4615: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9a6e0060, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
E/EGL_emulation: tid 4615: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9aac73e0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH

Comment: sorry for the format, im new here :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`class Loading extends AsyncTask {`

`@Override`

`protected Void doInBackground( Void... arg0)`

`{`

`// your code here`

`return null;`

`}`

`@Override`

`protected void onPreExecute()`

`{`

`//your code here`

`super.onPreExecute();`

`}`

`@Override`

`protected void onPostExecute(Void result)`

`{`

`//your code here`

`super.onPostExecute(result);`

`}`

`}//Loading`

Did you remember to add this line in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

and

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: thanks I'll try, about permissions yes I gave those permission ;)